# Color points of a scatterplot according to row numbers

Tags: r, plot

I made a simple scatterplot with this code:

```
plot(FB_MW$Ärger, w2v$aerger,
 main = "Ärger", 
 xlab = "Rating Fragebogen (MW)", 
 ylab = "word2vec")
```

Now I would like to colours according to the rows in my tablet called "w2v". Rows 1 to 6 should be depicted in blue, Rows 7 to 12 in red.

Another option might be to determine the the colour by a colum of the tablet called w2v$D which contains "yes" and "no" values.

Thanks a lot!
Lorena

Comment: It's usally easier if you show an example of your data used to create the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```r
w2v$color <- "blue"
w2v$color[w2v$D == "no"] <- "red"

plot(FB_MW$Ärger, w2v$aerger,
 main = "Ärger", 
 xlab = "Rating Fragebogen (MW)", 
 ylab = "word2vec",
 col  = w2v$color)
```

---

Another option is using `ggplot2`, which is usally a little bit more complex. In this case it's straight forward:

```r
ggplot(w2v, aes(x=FB_MW$Ärger, y=aerger, color=D)) +
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("Rating Fragebogen (MW)") + 
  ylab("word2vec") + 
  labs(title="Ärger") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! The first option brings out all the dots in blue. With the second one all the dots turn out in red. Any what I need to change?

Comment: I expected a column named `D` with values "yes" and "no". In the first option the default color is blue, all rows with "no" in column `D` are turned into red. The second option is basically the same. If all dots are of the same color, please take a look at your column `D`.

Comment: If it's just rows `1:6` should be blue, rows `7:12` red, you could try: `w2v$color <- rep(c("blue", "red"), each=6)`. In this case, for the second option, replace `color=D` with `color=color`.

Comment: You're right, something went wrong with the D column. Option 1 is working perfectly now. Thank you, Martin!